# Java. Отображение float и double

Tags: java, float

Есть простейший код:

```
private static float val = 0f;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
        val = val + 0.1f;
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

Ожидаю в конце получить `100000*0,1 = 10000`. Но последнее значение: `9998.557`.
Если запустите код — увидите, что значения отображаются неточно, должны быть четко с шагом `0,1` но вместо `0,8` — `0.8000001`, вместо `2000` — `2000.0587` и дальше ближе к максимальному значению — все больше погрешность. В чем дело?

Comment: Друзья, это просто пример для вопроса, я не стал грузить вас изначальной задачей. Изначальная задача была считать из файла число, округлить его и записать другой xls-файл ячейку. Ну и в ячейках у меня пошла эта хрень. Вместо 13,35 что-то типа 13,34999999721, а вот в экселе это нежелательно, так как затрудняет читабельность =(((

Answer (score 9):

Дело в типах double и float. В вычислениях, связанных с ними, практически всегда есть погрешности в вычислениях, связанные с округлением. Если хотите точности в таких числах, используйте BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

У Float типа точность гораздо ниже чем у Double. Если для вас критичен результат, то используйте Double.

Простейший пример демонстрирующий погрешность:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double dob = 0.1f;
    float flo = 0.1f;
    System.out.println("Float: " + flo);
    System.out.println("Double: " + dob);
}
```

Результат:

```
Float: 0.1
Double: 0.10000000149011612
```

В вашем коде если тип переменной изменить на Double, то получится то что вы ожидали от кода:

```
private static double val = .0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
            val = val + 0.1f;
            System.out.println(val);
        }
    }
```

Результат:

```
9999.700149007142
9999.800149008632
9999.900149010122
10000.000149011612
```

А если инкремент

```
val = val + 0.1f;
```

сменить на

```
val = val + 0.1;
```

то точность ещё больше возрастёт.

Answer (score 1):

Это фундаментальная проблема. 0.1 (как и большинство других дробных чисел) невозможно точно записать в двоичной системе, всегда будет погрешность. Чем больше разрядность (процессора), тем погрешность меньше, но она будет всегда. И чем больше вычислений накладываются друг на друга, тем больше отличия "компьютерного" результата от математического.

Отсюда следует, что нельзя сравнивать два float или double, полученных в результате вычислений, с помощью оператора `==`. Обычно определяют максимально допустимую погрешность `epsilon` и затем вычисляют, попадает ли разница между двумя числами в эту погрешность:

```
float epsilon = 0.00000001;    
float diff = f1 - f2;
if (diff < epsilon && diff > -epsilon){
    // здесь код
}
```